# Xcode 7 GM - Hide separator for one row in grouped UITableViewController

Tags: xcode, swift, separator

I'm using Xcode 7 GM with Swift. I'm trying to remove a separator for a specific row in a grouped table view with static cells. I made an outlet for a row, a UITableViewCell, and tried these 3 codes:

```
nameRow.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, CGRectGetWidth(nameRow.bounds)/2.0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(nameRow.bounds)/2.0)
```

and

```
nameRow.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

and

```
nameRow.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

None of them worked. What should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you can create an outlet to a specific row in Interface Builder. However, if you instead apply the inset in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it appears to be working just fine for me.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, CGRectGetWidth(cell.bounds)/2.0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(cell.bounds)/2.0)
    }

    return cell
}
```

#### Plain Style

[image: Simulator screenshot showing a table view with a hidden separator on one of the cells]

#### Grouped Style

[image: Simulator screenshot showing a grouped table view with a hidden separator on one of the cells]

Comment: I have the style "Grouped" not "Plain", so it doesnt work with my case. Tried it and it crashed

Comment: The code works for the grouped style as well (see the screenshot above). Make sure to register your cell class for the reuse identifier.